# Array of String/Integer PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Laravel array to `string/integer` conversion error.  I have a code in php where i need to have a variable of type "`string array`" and "`integer array`".  But it is showing an error as "`array to string conversion error`" when i try to declare them.  I am new to php so how can i do this php

```
class A
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $subject=[];
    public $nosubject;
    public $teacherid=[];
    public $hours=[];

    public function __construct()
    {
        settype($this->subject,"string");
        settype($this->hours,"integer");
        settype($this->teacherid,"integer");
    }}
```

Comment: So if you have array `$this->subject` - what's the string value of it you expect?

Comment: To have an array of subject names

Comment: You convert array to string, what do you expect as output?

Comment: Clearly, you cannot settype to "string" if the subject is "string array []". Could you not just drop the settype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to have a variable of type "string array"

Then you are using the wrong language, because PHP **does not have** a type "string array".

It has the type ["array"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), meaning "array of things that might be integers, strings, other arrays, objects, boolean, or a mix". It is, as the manual states, "actually an ordered map". Some languages call it a *dictionary*, a *map* or a *key-value store*. It is **not** what, for example, C calls "array".

You've already declared `subject` as array. That's all you can do. In the constructor, it makes no sense doing anything, because declaring the array as array would be redundant, and declaring it as anything else would cause an error.

What you can do, if needed, is to cast all members of the array to string when you do something with them.

For example, in a function such as returnSubjects, you might want to do

```
$this->subject = array_map(
    function($member) {
        settype($member, 'string');
        return $member;
    },
    $this->subject
);

return $this->subject;
```